# How to map currency code to custom code while sending to client-side from server-side

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, currency

I develop a kind of middleware(MW) between client and backend sides. MW gets a request from client-side, processes it, requests to the backend, gets response from backend, processes it, and returns a response to the client side. MW is developed as a Spring-boot project and uses jackson-datatype-jsr310 to send out JSON results.

MW creates java.util.Currency objects by using currency code information on response from the backend. However, I want to map a currency code to custom currency code while sending the client-side. For example: MW gets the currency code - "TRY" and Currency object is created. But, I want it to be sent as "TL" to the client-side.

How can I do it possible? Jackson mapper customisation class may be a solution for this problem, but how can I write this? or any other solution?